# How would I take items from two lists then input them into a string, without using dictionaries or zip

Tags: python

I'm quite new to python... so if

```
string_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
string_2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

how can I make it so it would print out:

```
a equals 1
b equals 2
c equals 3
d equals 4
```

I've tried:

```
for i in string_1:
    for j in string_2:
    print(i, "equals", j)
```

Comment: Will the length of both the string stay same all the time ?

Comment: Please check the indentation of code. Also why the name `string_n`? Those are lists and besides stating types in names is not helpful as it may seem at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already said, python has `zip` for just this purpose.  However,  if you insist on doing this without zip:

```
for i in range(len(string_1)):
    print(string_1[i] + ' equals ' + string_2[i])
```

will accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to use a dictionary for something like this.

E.g.

```
things = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

for k, v in things.items():
  print(k, 'equals', v)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
items_1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
items_2 = [1,2,3,4]

for a, b in zip(items_1, items_2):
    print ("{0} equals {1}".format(a, b)
```

Comment: I really don't know why, but the OP insists on not using `zip()`.